# Why is my script function being fired when the page loads without a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, events

I'm trying to use JQuery's on() function to attach an event to a button and any button that will be dynamically created and injected later on. However, when I run the test website, it calls alertMe() without clicking the button. alertMe is in a .js file and of course, I have the JQuery file. This is about as simple an example as I can create - am I missing something here with attaching this event with JQuery?

```
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('button').on("click", alertMe());
        });
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="1">
        <button data-attr="1">
            Say Sumfin'</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

`data-attr` is just a custom attribute that I'll use to identify the buttons I'll be attaching this too.

### EDIT

So the reason the question was asked will remain evident, I've left it as-is. But this is what I used to actually have the event properly attach to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-attr]', alertMe);
```

Comment: FYI, the way you are using `.on()` will not attach the click event to dynamically added buttons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
$( 'button' ).on( 'click', alertMe );
```

The `.on()` method expects a function reference as its second argument. Notice the difference:

```
alertMe // function reference

alertMe() // function invocation
```

Comment: ...dammit. It makes sense now that you pointed it out. If ever there was time for an 'smh' and a *facepalm*, now is that time.

Comment: Or that would also work : $( 'button' ).on( 'click', function(){alertMe();});

Comment: @darma -- why stop at one level of regression?  `function(){ (function() { alertMe();})(); }` will also work

Comment: @ŠimeVidas -- [Look deeper](http://www.thelastcitadel.com/_media/blag/hypnotoad.gif).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're putting parentheses after the function name!  That means, "call this function".